# Would a Matriarchal Society Be Likely to Practice Toplessness?

Tags: society, culture

Having read the Wikipedia article about toplessness, seem like many egalitarian societies practiced toplessness until they were influenced by the Europeans. So, would it be correct to assume that a matriarchal society has a good chance of practicing it?

Comment: Where would this society be living? Going topless in polar regions is not exactly a smart move from the evolutionary stand point, regardless if your culture is influenced or not by the European prudery.

Comment: @L.Dutch An environment that's similar to Italy.

Comment: What does your matriarchal society look like and how does it work - it's difficult to answer unless we know more. (It's not as if there are big obvious unproblematically definitivley matriarchal examples to draw from)

Comment: @FaySuggers It's just this regular human society with post-classical technology.

Comment: My mother responds: "Why would I want to be cold? Or sunburned?"

Comment: *"An environment that's similar to Italy":* Italy does have winter, you know; in parts of Italy winter is really winter, with frost and snow, and even in southern Italy I wouldn't recommend going about topless in winter. (For example, the forecast for tommorrow's *maximum* temperature in Naples is a cool 14 °C, 57 °F). And they actually do practice toplessness in Italy, when appropriate, for example, in summer at the beach.

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain how toplessness is a natural consequence of matriarchal society.  Many human societies seem to have no particular problem with topless females, and climate isn't really that much of a factor. Tierra del Fuegans lived pretty much naked until the kindly Europeans got down there and explained them the meaning of the word "cold".

Comment: @elemtilas, I suspect you'll find that climate very much plays a factor when the climate is more extreme. Being fully covered outside is common in places like the Tibetan Plateau and the subarctic areas of Eurasia and North America.

Comment: @KeithMorrison -- I don't disagree, but that is why I specifically mention Tierra del Fuego!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**OK, I just realized my comments constituted too much of an answer to be left as comments**

**Observation #1:** Toplessness is cultural, not political. There are cultures all around the earth, patriarchal and matriarchal, that practice toplessness. A very uneducated observation is the more tribal the society, the more likely clothes are irrelevant. Jumping to the conclusion that toplessness is a function (much less a primary function) of gender politics is ignoring some remarkable anthropological complexities. The simplest answer to this question is "maybe" because too many things unrelated to matriarchy can influence the decision.

**Observation #2:** Suggesting that matriarchy could influence toplessness suggests that women are either more or less likely to want (genetically disposed vs. culturally disposed) to be topless. Considering both sexes somewhat prefer toplessness when advancing the cause of procreation, that's an assumption that might be very difficult to prove. Back in the good old days (millions of years ago) I suspect gender had nothing to do with the desire to be topless.  This seems confirmed as very young children (say, pre-4-year-olds, before they start really reacting to cultural conditioning) don't seem to care one way or another if they wear clothes (some, and I've seen both sexes do it, seem to fight against clothing entirely). Therefore, I personally would need to see scholarly proof that gender (much less gender politics) had any bias toward toplessness.

**Conclusion**

The only answer is "maybe."

Simply changing the social structure from patriarchy to matriarchy isn't enough to rationalize increased or decreased toplessness.  The cultural underpinings are still there leading to today's western culture of accepting male toplessness more than female toplessness, but one would need to justify that matriarchy would be more or less likely to be influenced by the nearly innumerable historical influences (which include art, religion, politics, technology, climate, and a great deal more) that did or did not promote toplessness to know if it could.

Without that analysis, it would be difficult to rationalize that even the male-dominant-acceptability of toplessness would change.  Remember, there was a time when "good society" didn't brook toplessness for either gender.

Comment: A good example of the cultural issue is India. The Malayali in Kerala *required* Hindu women other than those of Brahmin and Kshatriya castes to be topless prior to 1858 when it was allowed for all women to be covered in public, and before the Islamic conquests it wasn't uncommon in northern India for upper class women to be covered up while lower class women were topless.

Answer (score 5):

In warmer climes it would be preferred simply because clothing is both unneeded and a health hazard. The sort of culture makes no difference. Polynesians, Melanesians and Micronesians used to go topless because it's cooler and healthier, only when Europeans showed up and forced european ideas of modesty on them did they start covering up, and now there are skin problems and other issues which never used to occur.

Whether a society puts a taboo of some sort on exposing breasts is another factor. But patriarchy, matriarchy don't make a difference, these cultures had both. Clothings original need was for comfort and protection against the environment, not modesty.

One other factor is the composition of the clothing, cottons predominance is pretty recent in many places. Clothing made from other things can be pretty abrasive or hard to keep clean.

Comment: The Spanish complained a LOT about female "indecency" in the Philippines. If I remember right, our toplessness seemed more tied to social class: 1) Peasant women didn't wear shirts, much like their men; 2) "no shirts" may have been a mark of slavery, since everyone fought each other and took captives; and 3) nobles wore elaborate robes and tunics, but they were often VERY sheer and clearly said "I'm rich, LOOK AT MY OUTFIT!" not "I am hiding my chest from prying eyes," so once they got sweaty or rained on (pretty common in, you know, the tropics), it was as good as wearing nothing.